# iPhone-Sqlite:Constraint failed error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, database, sqlite

This is my code :

```
- (void) addOrder {


    if(addStmt == nil) {

        const char *sql = "insert into item(menuid,itemName,price,quantity,spiciness) Values( ?, ?, ?, ?,?)";

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    // NSLog(@"ADDSTMT:%@",addStmt);
    sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 1, [menuID integerValue]);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [itemName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_double(addStmt, 3, price );
    sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 4, [quantity integerValue]);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 5, [spiciness UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else 
        menuID = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithLongLong:sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database)];

    //Reset the add statement.
    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
}
```

Here data is inserted into DB but got the error "Constraint Failed"

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: What are the types of your variables? What values are in the DB now? Use intValue rather than integerValue to get an integer from another type.

Comment: This is my table structure : menuID-integer,itemname-string,price-float,quantity-integer,spicines-string

Comment: In the sql you write `itemName` and in the DB table `itemname` - I wonder if that is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi may b this code will help you. insert data with this style.

```
sqlite3_stmt *stment;
    stment =nil;

    NSString *sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into DateSave(Date,Name) Values('%@','%@')",Date,strTestName];

    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &stment, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            sqlite3_step(stment);
            testID =sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stment);
    sqlite3_close(database);
```