# SQLITE3 Constraint Failed

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, prepared-statement

My first question on stackoverflow and I really hope you guys can help me.

I've been trying to get prepared statements running in objective C and so far so good.
But now I keep getting "Constraint failed" on my database when trying to add a track.

I've already deleted the db and created it again but the error remains.
Also I have been looking into the duplicate key but I don't see me adding a duplicate anywhere.
The locations table adds just fine and it's built kind of the same.

My DB:

```
CREATE TABLE locations
    (LocationID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    TimestampGPS DATE NOT NULL,
    Longitude REAL NOT NULL,
    Latitude REAL NOT NULL,
    Altitude REAL NOT NULL,
    Accuracy REAL NOT NULL,
    Bearing REAL NOT NULL,
    Speed REAL NOT NULL,
    TimestampDevice DATE NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE tracks
    (TrackID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Title VARCHAR,
    Description VARCHAR,
    StartTrackDeviceTime DATE NOT NULL,
    EndTrackDeviceTime DATE NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE track_locations
    (TrackID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES tracks(TrackID), 
    LocationID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES locations(LocationID),
    PRIMARY KEY (TrackID, LocationID));
```

My code to add a track. (I have got code to add a location which is similar and that one works just fine)

```c
const char *sqlTrack = "INSERT INTO tracks(Title, Description, StartTrackDeviceTime, EndTrackDeviceTime) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db.dataBase, sqlTrack, -1, &addTrackStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db.dataBase));
}

sqlite3_bind_text(addTrackStatement, 1, [track.title UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(addTrackStatement, 2, [track.description UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(addLocationStatement, 3, [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:track.startTime] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(addTrackStatement, 4, [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:track.endTime] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

NSLog(@"Going to execute the statement");
if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addTrackStatement)) {
    NSLog(@"First step failed");
    NSLog(@"Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db.dataBase));
    return NO;
}
else {
    long insertedTrack = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db.dataBase);
    NSLog(@"Inserted id on TRACK: %ld", insertedTrack);

    //HERE I ALSO ADD LOCATIONS

    sqlite3_clear_bindings(addTrackStatement);
    sqlite3_reset(addTrackStatement);
}
```

Comment: What is contained within the track.title & description fields, and what is spat out by the NSDateFormatter lines you have?  I'd log exactly what is being passed into the four sqlite3_bind_text functions before they are called and post that here.  Perhaps something is not what you expect (e.g. "" or <null> instead of nil) or a blank date where you have a not null constraint.

Comment: I've used NSLog on everything and all values are filled in just fine

Title: MyTitle
Descr: MyDescr
Startdate: 2012-04-19 10:26:52GMT+02:00
Enddate: 2012-04-19 10:26:52GMT+02:00

The NSDateFormatter is built as following:
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];

Dateformatter is also used within locations where it works just fine

Comment: Cool. Hmm.  Another user has a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426843/iphone-sqliteconstraint-failed-error .  The provided solution to that was to use an alternative insert syntax.  Now I'm not recommending it as I don't like it, but does that make the problem go away?

Comment: This does indeed make the problem go away. But if this is so, what is wrong in the bindings?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm puzzling over too; and also why I didn't posit it as an answer to the question.  Avoiding the question entirely isn't really an answer in my book. :D

Comment: Shouldn't this: `sqlite3_bind_text(addLocationStatement, 3, [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:track.startTime] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);` read `sqlite3_bind_text(addTrackStatement, 3, [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:track.startTime] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);`

Comment: Facepalm. I just found the problem.

Seems like my third bind was taking the wrong statement (addLocationStatement instead of addTrackStatement). This took me a day to figure out. Thanks all for the help guys!

@Diziet : Yes indeed. Just found it too. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah I just posted that. :D  If you're feeling magnanimous you could accept the answer. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should this line:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(addLocationStatement, 3, [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:track.startTime] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

read:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(addTrackStatement, 3, [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:track.startTime] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```